# File Upload to S3 is occasionally 0 KB

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

We are using S3 to store excel files. I first parse through the file to grab some data to save to the database before I upload it to the S3 bucket. Though I have yet to get this to happen on my local machine, when this is deployed, the tester sometimes sees the uploaded file being 0 KB even though it was parsed and data was saved to the database.It doesn't happen on my machine and only happens when deployed intermittently. Any ideas of how to resolve this?

```
    [HttpPost("ingesttestmatrix")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestMatrixResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult<string> IngestTestMatrix([FromForm] Guid authenticateduserid, [FromForm] Guid testeventid, IFormFile filename)
    {
        TestMatrixResponse rsp = new TestMatrixResponse();
        List<string> BadDataColumns = new List<string>();
        Guid TestMatrixID = Guid.NewGuid();
        //string newDictName = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\TempFiles" + Guid.NewGuid();
        string newDictName = AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"\TempLLDBFiles" + Guid.NewGuid();
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newDictName);
        string baseFileName = Request.Form.Files[0].FileName;
        string newFileName = newDictName + @"\" + baseFileName;

        try
        {
            //create file from stream and then open it for ingesting                
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
            }
            //Do some cool db stuff
            Model.Managers.AmazonFileManager.UploadFile(newFileName, testeventid.ToString()).Wait();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rsp.message = ex.Message.Replace("\"", "");
            LoggingEvent lge = new LoggingEvent(LoggingEventTypeEnum.Error, "Ingest Test Matrix ", ex.Message, authenticateduserid.ToString());
            LoggingEventController leController = new LoggingEventController();
            leController.InsertLoggingEvent(authenticateduserid, lge, LoggingEventTypeEnum.Error);
            rsp.success = false;
       }};

    public static async Task UploadFile(string filePath, string itemGuid)
    {

        try
        {
            var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
            string bucketName = "";
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWSBucketName")))
                bucketName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWSBucketName");
            else
                bucketName = _iConfig.GetSection("AWSBucketName").Value;

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {

                BucketName = bucketName,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                Key = itemGuid + "/",
                ContentBody = itemGuid
            };

            await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest);

            string fileKey = itemGuid + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, fileKey);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                ||
                amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                throw new Exception("AWS Error: Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("AWS Error: " + amazonS3Exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `originalFileName` ?

Comment: Sorry. I corrected. I was trying to condense the code a little to make it more readable. OriginalFileName is the original file. If it is a xls, I was having to save it as an xlsx file for parsing. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why is your controller Synchronous?